# how to send an email from a windows batch

Tags: windows, cmd

I would like to send an email from a windows batch with an attachment knowing that the recipient is a distribution list in outlook. 
could you offer me a solution by answering these questions: 
Windows module to be installed, 
Is a Windows service must be installed, whether automatic or not? 
Which protocols to use?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290152/how-do-i-send-an-email-from-a-dos-batch-command

Comment: What did you research before asking? SO is not a recommendation site (which this question is kind of asking).

Comment: Super User might be a better site to ask on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a simple email from a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038926/how-to-send-a-simple-email-from-a-windows-batch-file)